# Can we use mundane for objects?

Tags: word-usage

According to [dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/mundane) mundane means:

> ordinary and not interesting or exciting

but all examples are about job, work, tasks and other abstract  things. I wonder if I can use mundane for things such as my laptop:

> I had been using a mundane laptop for a couple of years before I bought my macbook.

Is it natural to say "mundane laptop"?

Comment: Only if there are exciting and extraordinary laptops. So maybe it isn't the right word, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: It sounds a bit like something an Apple salesman might say.

Comment: "The Wonderfully Mundane New iPhone" - _New Yorker_ September 10 2013 - ... "But there may be no better sign of progress than when the future feels mundane".

Comment: "Hundreds of mundane classics will converge on Grimsthorpe Castle in Lincolnshire for the [Festival of the Unexceptional](https://www.hagerty.co.uk/articles/events-articles/festival-of-the-unexceptional/hagertys-festival-of-the-unexceptional-returns-on-31-july-to-celebrate-the-most-marvellously-mundane-motor-cars/) – Britain’s biggest celebration of ordinary motors." - a festival of ordinary cars made from 1966 to 1996, with a prize for the most ordinary (in 2019, won by a 1977 Morris Marina estate).

Comment: There are a lot of more common ways of describing such a laptop, e.g. "basic", "run-of-the-mill", "ordinary", "bog standard", "regular", "normal"...